# Check Website is TLS or SSL and its version

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, windows-server-2012

We have a website hosted in our server. How can we check the protocol of that website. I mean I need to identify the website is TLS or SSL. My requirement is that , First I need to check the TLS/SSL version of that my wesbite and then I need to modify the payment section in website if the website protocol is below TLS 1.2.

Comment: Related question & answer on how to do it in other browsers (Firefox, Opera, etc.): https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19096/how-to-determine-if-a-browser-is-using-an-ssl-or-tls-connection

Answer (score 14):

To know which SSL/TLS security protocol is being used by a particular website:

1. Open **Google Chrome** or **Microsoft Edge** browser.
2. Navigate to the URL of the website that you are interested in knowing which SSL/TLS version is being used.
3. Press the <kbd>F12</kbd> keyboard key.
4. Navigate to the [Security tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eklif.png).
5. Under Connections, the SSL/TLS protocol version will be displayed, e.g.,

   > Connection - secure connection settings. The connection to this site is encrypted and authenticated using TLS 1.2, ECDHE_RSA with P-256, and AES_128_GCM.

Comment: The 'Security' tab may not show up by default in Edge's Dev panel.  Click the '+' button in the toolbar to add it,  [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSAhV.png)

Comment: Now seems to be under "⋮ > More Tools"

Answer (score 6):

If you have the OpenSSL client installed:

`openssl s_client -showcerts -connect host:443`

Answer (score 5):

**If the Site Publicly Accessible**

If the website is publicly accessible then I would run it through [SSL Labs Server Test](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/) as this will give you a rating for your website overall. There is a section called Configuration in the results that shows you which protocols and ciphers your site supports.

**If the Site is Internal**

[TestSSLServer](http://www.bolet.org/TestSSLServer/) is part of the SSL Labs Server Test but if you download the executable then it can be run locally and works on internal sites.

```
TestSSLServer.exe [ options ] servername [ port ]
```

When this has been ran if the result does not contain a section for SSLv3 or SSLv2 then it is not supported.

```
C:\Users\Struthers\Downloads>TestSSLServer4.exe localhost
Connection: localhost:443
SNI: localhost
  TLSv1.0:
     server selection: enforce server preferences
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
  TLSv1.1: idem
  TLSv1.2:
     server selection: enforce server preferences
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3f- (key:  RSA)  DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
     3-- (key:  RSA)  RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
=========================================
+++++ SSLv3/TLS: 1 certificate chain(s)
+++ chain: length=1
names match:        yes
includes root:      yes
signature hash(es):
+ certificate order: 0
thumprint:  D09BBE93C1B78A1B50597636A51592459217E559
serial:     50AAC4F83B5DA8B148C13CF99DA35879
subject:    CN=localhost
issuer:     CN=localhost
valid from: 2016-12-14 10:13:31 UTC
valid to:   2021-12-14 00:00:00 UTC
key type:   RSA
key size:   2048
sign hash:  SHA-256
(self-issued)
server names:
   localhost
=========================================
Server compression support: no
Server time: 2017-02-13 15:02:22 UTC (offset: -326 ms)
Secure renegotiation support: yes
SSLv2 ClientHello format (for SSLv3+): yes
Minimum DH size: 2048
DH parameter reuse: yes
Minimum EC size (no extension):   256
Minimum EC size (with extension): 256
ECDH parameter reuse: yes
Supported curves (size and name) ('*' = selected by server):
  * 256  secp256r1 (P-256)
    384  secp384r1 (P-384)
=========================================
WARN[CS005]: Server supports RC4.
WARN[CS006]: Server supports cipher suites with no forward secrecy.
```